# Only the first result is printed in the CSV file

Tags: perl, loops, csv, for-loop

I am printing 110000 fileds one by one in CSV file but it is printing only the first result in the file

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;   
use warnings;
use Switch;
use Text::CSV_XS;
use Data::Dumper;
use File::Slurp;
use LWP::Simple;
use Parallel::ForkManager;

my @links=("doba_media26.upcs");
my $pm = new Parallel::ForkManager(16); 

foreach my $linkarray (@links) {
    $pm->start and next; # do the fork
    my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({
        binary => 1,
        eol => "\r\n",
        sep_char => "\t"
    }) or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV_XS->error_diag ();   
    open my $sample, ">:encoding(utf8)", $linkarray."_sample.csv" 
        or die "result.csv: $!";
    my @lines = read_file( $linkarray );
    my $numLines = @lines;

    foreach my $line(@lines) {
        eval {
            my @tabs;
            print $line;
            push (@tabs,"");
            push (@tabs,"");
            push (@tabs,"");
            push (@tabs,$line);
            my @line = "\n";
            $csv->print($sample,\@tabs);
        }
    };
    if ($@) {
        redo;
        sleep(1200);
    }
    $pm->finish; # do the exit in the child process
}
$pm->wait_all_children;
```

The file has 11,000 results but the above code is printing only the first field in csv file?

Comment: Are you running several threads at the same time, writing to the same file (`doba_media26.upcs_sample.csv`), and overwriting it every time with `>` mode? Perhaps that is your problem? Not sure I understand what it is you think these threads are doing differently from each other.

Comment: Also, all those `push` statements can be combined: `push @tabs, "", "", "", $line`. Or just simply: `my @tabs = ("", "", "", $line)`. You should clean up your code and remove unused things, such as `$numLines`, `Switch` (which is also deprecated and should not be used), `@line`, etc.

Comment: I don't think there is a risk of overwriting with only one item in the array but I'm unable to install the module to test. Does the error occur when you remove the forking logic? If you remove the eval does it die with a message? The error is not handled until the loop exits, which seems incorrect. It will be ignored until then.